# Kubernetes deployment fails

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubectl, kube-controller-manager

I have `Pod` and `Service` `ymal` files in my system. I want to run these two using `kubectl create -f <file>` and connect from outside browser to test connectivity.Here what I have followed.

My Pod :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: client-nginx
  labels:
    component: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: client
      image: nginx 
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

My Services file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: client-nginx-port
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3050
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 31616
  selector:
    component: web
```

I used `kubectl create -f my_pod.yaml` and then `kubectl get pods` shows my pod `client-nginx`

And then `kubectl create -f my_service.yaml`, No errors here and then shows all the services.

When I try to curl to service, it gives

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.10 port 31616: Connection refused.

`kubectl get deployments` doesnt show my pod. Do I have to deploy it? I am a bit confused. If I use instructions [given here](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/kubernetes/how-to-deploy-nginx-on-a-kubernetes-cluster/), `I can deploy`nginx`successfully and access from outside browsers.`

I used instructions [given here](http://containertutorials.com/get_started_kubernetes/k8s_example.html) to test this.

Comment: try to use service IP and port instead of pod IP.

Comment: @PrateekSen No luck, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: client-nginx-port
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3050
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31616
  selector:
    component: web
```

Comment: Done, `targetPort: 80`, must be 80 for `nginx`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You missed selector name to be given to pod yaml which will be picked by service where you have mentioned the selector as component

Use this in pod yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: client-nginx
  labels:
    component: web
spec:
  selector:
    component: nginx
  containers:
    - name: client
      image: nginx 
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Useful links:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

Comment: Your yaml is invalid.

Comment: `error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec): unknown field "selector" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec;`