# Kubernetes ErrImageNeverPull with k3s and docker save

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s

I'm trying to deploy a local image to my raspberry pi kubernetes cluster:

```bash
$ sudo kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION
oren2         Ready    <none>                 40m    v1.28.4+k3s2
oren1         Ready    <none>                 39m    v1.28.4+k3s2
oren4         Ready    <none>                 42m    v1.28.4+k3s2
raspberrypi   Ready    control-plane,master   167m   v1.28.4+k3s2
```

My docker image is ready:

```bash
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
translator   latest    fd8afed3a99b   27 minutes ago   1.04GB
```

And I upload it:

```bash
$ sudo docker save translator | sudo k3s ctr images import -
$ sudo k3s ctr images ls | grep translator
docker.io/library/translator:latest
# ... omitted ...
```

I'm using the following yaml (adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849403/kubernetes-deployment-fails)):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: translator
  labels:
    component: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: translator
      image: translator
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
  restartPolicy: Never
```

When I try to get my pods it doesn't work:

```bash
$ sudo kubectl create -f config.yml 
pod/translator created
$ sudo kubectl get pods
NAME               READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
translator-g9rlh   0/1     ErrImageNeverPull   0          20m
translator         0/1     ErrImageNeverPull   0          12s
```

---

my question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392041/getting-errimageneverpull-in-pods), but does not *use* `Minikube`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
+----------------+             +---------------------+           
|                |             |                     |           
|   Docker Host  |             | Kubernetes Cluster  |           
|                |             | (Raspberry Pi, k3s) |          
+-------+--------+             +------+----------+---+          
        |                             |          |             
        |                             |          |             
        |  docker save                | kubectl  |             
        +---------------------------> | create   |             
        |                             |          |             
        |  Docker Image: translator   |          |             
        +---------------------------> |          |             
                                      +----------+
```

Since you are using a local image, you need to make sure the image name in the Kubernetes YAML matches the name used in your Docker environment: `docker.io/library/translator:latest`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: translator
  labels:
    component: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: translator
      image: docker.io/library/translator:latest  # Use the full image name
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
  restartPolicy: Never
```

And check that the image is available on each node:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Fetch the list of node names from Kubernetes
NODES=$(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}')

# Loop through each node
for NODE in $NODES; do
    echo "Checking image on $NODE..."

    # Run the command to check for the image and store the output
    # Replace 'username' with the appropriate username for SSH access
    IMAGE_CHECK=$(ssh username@"$NODE" 'docker images | grep translator')

    # Check if the output contains the image name
    if [[ -z "$IMAGE_CHECK" ]]; then
        echo "Image 'translator' is MISSING on node $NODE"
    else
        echo "Image 'translator' is PRESENT on node $NODE"
    fi

    echo "-----------------------------------"
done
```

---

Finally, if your local Docker image `translator` is only available on a specific node (or a subset of nodes) in your Kubernetes cluster, you need to make sure your pod is scheduled on a node where the image is present.  That is particularly important since you have multiple nodes (`oren2`, `oren1`, `oren4`, `raspberrypi`) in your cluster.

To achieve this, you can use either [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes-using-node-affinity/) or [Taints and Toleration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) in your Kubernetes configuration:

- **Node affinity** allows you to constrain which nodes your pod can be scheduled on, based on labels on nodes.
  For example, if the `translator` image is only available on `oren2`, you can add a label to `oren2` and update your pod specification to include node affinity for this label.
- **Taints and toleration** involves applying a taint to nodes that do not have the `translator` image, and adding a corresponding toleration to the pod specification. That way, Kubernetes will not schedule the pod on nodes that have a taint which the pod does not tolerate.

For instance, here is how to add node affinity to your Kubernetes configuration, assuming `oren2` is labeled appropriately (e.g., `has-translator-image=true`):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: translator
  labels:
    component: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: translator
      image: docker.io/library/translator:latest
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
  restartPolicy: Never
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: has-translator-image
            operator: In
            values:
            - "true"
```

By adding node affinity or taints and toleration, you can make sure your pod is scheduled on a node where the necessary Docker image is available, which will prevent potential issues related to image availability across different nodes in your cluster.

---

> Other than the name fix, I think your answer made me realize something I missed: I have to run `sudo docker save translator | sudo k3s ctr images import -` for every worker node, right?
>
> I was somehow thinking my worker nodes only need to have docker installed, and the actual image (translator) would be "automagically" sent to them.

In a Kubernetes cluster, especially one that is not using a centralized container registry, each worker node needs to have the required Docker image available locally if the [`imagePullPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy) is set to `Never`: it means Kubernetes will not attempt to pull the image from a remote registry.

Since you are using k3s, which has its own container runtime (`containerd`), you need to import the Docker image into k3s's image store on each node. That is not automatically handled by Kubernetes or k3s. The command `sudo docker save translator | sudo k3s ctr images import -` does this for the node it is executed on, but it does not distribute the image to other nodes in the cluster.

If your nodes are labelled, to identify the nodes where you want to deploy the image (e.g., `has-translator-image=true`), you can script this (`chmod +x deploy_image.sh`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Label that identifies the nodes where the image should be deployed
LABEL_SELECTOR="has-translator-image=true"

# Docker image to be saved and transferred
DOCKER_IMAGE="translator"

# Save the Docker image as a tarball
sudo docker save "$DOCKER_IMAGE" > "$DOCKER_IMAGE.tar"

# Fetch the list of node names that have the specified label
NODES=$(kubectl get nodes -l $LABEL_SELECTOR -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}')

# Loop through each node
for NODE in $NODES; do
    echo "Transferring image to $NODE"

    # Transfer the tarball to the node
    scp "$DOCKER_IMAGE.tar" username@"$NODE":~

    echo "Importing image on $NODE"
    # SSH into the node, import the image, and then optionally remove the tarball
    ssh username@"$NODE" "sudo k3s ctr images import ~/$DOCKER_IMAGE.tar && rm ~/$DOCKER_IMAGE.tar"

    echo "Image imported successfully on $NODE"
    echo "------------------------------------"
done

# Optionally remove the tarball from the local machine
rm "$DOCKER_IMAGE.tar"
```

Make sure you have SSH keys set up for passwordless access to each node.

That would transfer the image tarball over the network to each node and requires sufficient disk space on both the source machine and the target nodes.

Comment: So other than the name fix, I think your answer made me realize something I missed: I have to run `sudo docker save translator | sudo k3s ctr images import -` for *every worker node*, right? I was somehow under the impression that my worker nodes only need to have `docker` installed, and the actual image (`translator`) would be "automagically" sent to them

Comment: @OrenIshShalom True. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing image tag in your container spec.
Change your pod config image definition to: `docker.io/library/translator:latest`.
You might also verify if this image is present on your worker nodes, as you have image pull policy set to `Never`